# Ubuntu on Acer E1-510

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

So I have an Acer E1-510-2821 Computer I recently purchased at Walmart. The computer came pre-installed with Windows 8.1. The system of course is UEFI, and unfortunately has no legacy Bios mode.

I have tried Ubuntu 12.04, Ubuntu 13.10, and Kubuntu 13.10 and, each will show the grub bootloader and allows me to enter my boot parameters if I want. I have tried noapic, nolapic, and of course nomodeset, yet each time the computer only goes to a black screen.

I have noticed however that in the case of Kubuntu, it actually showed the installer and allowed me to choose "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu", however as soon as I click Try it only goes to a black screen like all the rest. This is the only environment however that I even seen an active mouse. I did not try clicking Install Kubuntu as I do not want to install if I cannot get it to run.

I tried removing `quiet splash` and it showed the kernel booting, and each time after booting it would simply show the prompt rather than go to a desktop. If I run `sudo service lightdm start` then it just goes to the black screen again.

The system has an Intel Celeron Quad Core CPU N2920 with integrated graphics, so it's not a proprietary graphics card. Any help to get this running Ubuntu would be appreciated, as I hate Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a laptop? Does it have screen brightness keys? If so, try using them; the screen might simply be dimmed.

If that fails, my next suggestion is much more painful: It's to boot to text mode and create an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file and try adjusting its options (particularly the X driver you're using). This is a very open-ended approach, though, and potentially rather complex. Try doing a Web search on `xorg.conf` to find tutorials on how to create and use this file.

Of course, another option is to return the computer; if it's a recent purchase, you can probably do so and get your money back. You can then research what works painlessly with Linux and get something better.

Comment: The screen isn't dimmed, I tried that anyway but the fact the console shows and you can tell the backlight is on, its not the backlight. I don't feel like Xorg config, I'll just use the other laptop I got unless there are other suggestions that work haha.